# How to set TCP flags "&syn!=syn" in iptables?

Tags: iptables, firewall, tcp, nftables, flags

I have requirement where am getting parameters to set in iptables as below:

Rate Limit = 1/sec

Source port = 5432

Source IP = 203.0.113.0

Protocol = tcp

**TCP flags = &syn!=syn**

`iptables -A PRIO_IN -p tcp -s 203.0.113.0 --sport 5432 -j ACCEPT --tcp-flags " "`

How to pass input parameters of tcp flgas to command line?

What is the meaning of `&syn!=syn` ?

Comment: `& syn != syn` means that the syn flag is cleared, as in `!= syn` means that "any case but only the syn flag is set". Probably both `--tcp-flags SYN NONE` and `! --tcp-flags SYN SYN` are equivalent to `& syn != syn`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But when i check with chatgpt am getting `!=syn` as `! --tcp-flags SYN SYN`. And `&syn!= syn` as `--tcp-flags SYN SYN -m u32 --u32 "!(12 & 0x2C=0x2C)"`.

Comment: Well, I can't explain for an answer for a robot. Ask the robot to explain / assure you that its answer is correct, maybe. What I can offer is, you can read the `iptables-extensions` man page and get to know what "bit masking" means. The equivalent of `tcp flags != syn` *should be* `! --tcp-flags ALL SYN`. (I can't guarantee that nftables devs won't get it wrong when they implement it either though. Sometimes they might even choose to stick with bad/wrong stuff since they think correcting it "would violate existing assumption".)

Comment: My advice is, believe in semantics and experiment for actual behavior if really paranoid (certainly you'll need to be capable enough), and ask on the netfilter mailing list in a smart way if necessary instead of asking a robot that is known to be immature.

Comment: @TomYan: Thanks for the answers. Any idea what will be the interpretation for `& (syn | ack) == syn | ack`. I got this sample from `ip6tables` man page. Is it similar to `--tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK` ?

Comment: Yes, AFACIT, they are equivalent to each other.